# Why does gnuplot plot this file incorrectly?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file that consists of data like this:

```
0,1566
1,1602
2,1534
3,1505
4,1487
.
.
.
1193,1278
1194,1262
1195,1235
```

When I plot it with gnuplot (using `plot 'data.csv' using 0:1`), I get a line from 0,0 to roughly 1200, 1200. Like this: [image]

I don't understand why the plot looks like this. I don't even have any points near (0,0) and the y values should be decreasing with increasing x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set datafile separator ","
plot 'data.csv' using 1:2
```

Answer (score 0):

column numbering in gnuplot starts with 1, i.e. the first column number is 1. Hence, the correct command would be 'plot 'data.csv' using 1:2' in your example. (the zeroth column is an index, i.e. the number of the lines in the file)